# Custom legend in wpf chart

Tags: wpf, charts, legend

Firstly, I am very new to wpf and XAML.  The majority of my background is with Windows forms apps.

I have a very simple chart with three Line Series bound to data objects.  I would like to customize the legend to show not only the Line Series colors and titles, but also add a textblock under each legend item to display the last data point value in the series.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="{StaticResource graphBackground}" >
            <Grid.Resources >
                <Style TargetType="charting:LineSeries" >
                    <Setter Property="PolylineStyle" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="Polyline" >
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="LegendItemStyle" TargetType="charting:LegendItem" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>    
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:LegendItem}">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Background}" />
                                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="18" Margin="10"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <charting:Chart FontWeight="Bold">
                <charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Path=graphmax}" Interval="{Binding Path=graphinterval}" ShowGridLines="True" FontSize="18" />                            
                    <charting:DateTimeAxis Orientation="X" FontSize="18" Minimum="{Binding Path=datemin}" Maximum="{Binding Path=datemax}" IntervalType="Months" Interval="1" />
                </charting:Chart.Axes>
                <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dataPoints}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" Title="13 Wk" LegendItemStyle="{DynamicResource LegendItemStyle}">
                    <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                        </Style>                                   
                    </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>                        
                </charting:LineSeries>
```

Comment: I know the problem is with the TextBlock binding in the ControlTemplate, but don't know how the binding should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using {Binding}, which would bind to your DataContext object, which I believe is in this case is the LegendItem itself.  Here's a good explanation of [what {Binding} does](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=5).  You would either want to add a path to get a specific property, or use a converter to format the result the way you want.

Comment: Binding to a specific path is, I think, what I'm trying to do.  I just haven't been able to get the path correct.  The path I'm looking for is the dependent value of the Line Series corresponding to the legend value.  Something like this maybe?  '<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=charting:LineSeries, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DependentValuePath}"'

Comment: Imagine a standard legend with a colored rect and a title based on the LineSeries it represents.  Then under the title add a textblock that displays the most current value of the LineSeries.  As an example, if i have a line series representing the daily high temperatures for the year, the textblock would display the most recent recorded daily high.

Comment: OK.  So you would set the path for the binding to the property with the line series data, then use a value converter to return only the last point as text, formatted how you want.

Comment: Update:  I conceded on this one.  My chart contains 3 separate line series so I couldn't bind the textblock directly to a property of my data model and I was not able to find the correct binding.  I assume it exists, but I don't know where.  Eventually I hid the legend and created my own.  @AresAvatar:  on a side note, your suggestion of a value converter was exactly what I needed to capture the last point for each of the line series, so kudos to you.